# Como eu faço para o codigo ler um novo valor se a condição não for atendida? - C

Tags: c, loop

O código é este, está em C

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
int i;

printf("digite um inteiro");
scanf("%d",&i);



 while(i>=1){
  
printf("%d\n",i);
i=i-1; 
}
}
```

Mas eu quero que se for inserido um valor não válido como -1 por exemplo ,ele peça um novo valor e realizar as instruções while. Como posso fazer isso? Desde já agradeço pela atenção.

Comment: Se ele deve pedir de novo, por que não usa a função `scanf` novamente? Não entendi porque ele exibe o valor de `i` e depois vai decrementando.

Comment: Substitua `printf("digite um inteiro"); scanf("%d",&i);` por `printf("digite um inteiro"); scanf("%d",&i); while (i < 1) { printf("Valor inválido. Redigite um inteiro"); scanf("%d",&i);}`.

Answer (score 2):

Tem muitas opções!
1ª Validar a entrada:

```
int main(void){
  int i;
  do{
    printf("Digite um inteiro: ");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    if(i<1) printf("Entrada invalida\n");
  }while(i<1);
  
  while(i>=1){
     printf("%d\n",i);
     i=i-1; 
  }
}
```

2ª Utilizar o `scanf` dentro de outro tipo de estrutura de repetição:

```
int main(void){
 int i;

 do{
   printf("digite um inteiro");
   scanf("%d",&i);

   while(i>=1){
  
     printf("%d\n",i);
     i=i-1; 
   }
  }while(i!=0); //Esta condição diz que se a entrada for 0 ele irá parar de pedir entradas
}
```

3ª Dar o "chute inicial" para o `i`:

```
int main(void){
  int i = 1;//Aqui dou o chute inicial

  while(i!=0){//Não irá executar novamente caso o 'i' seja 0
    printf("digite um inteiro");
    scanf("%d",&i);

    while(i>=1){
      printf("%d\n",i);
      i=i-1; 
    }
  }
}
```